# access chunkContext within a step

Tags: spring-batch

I'd like to use the value of

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getReadCount();
```

, which represents the record # that I'm reading->processing->writing, within my processor.

I'm having trouble getting my chunkContext available. How do I make chunkContext available in my processor?

I assumed it was autowired into the job, but I might not be doing that correctly. I'm new to this sort of advanced java stuff, would appreciate any help (and patience)!

Comment: What `ItemReader` are you using?  For this use case, a better option is to use the `ItemCountAware` interface...

Answer (score 0):

You can add below conde in processor to access `StepExecution`

```
  @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

    }
```